# Cannot setup eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I had tried hours to setup `eslint-plugin-vue`, but the lint output is always empty (no stdout and stderr), I must have missed something very basic?

Commands

```
$ node --version # v9.4.0
$ npm install
$ $(npm bin)/eslint . # Empty output
```

File structure

```
Foo
├── .eslintrc.js
├── main.vue
└── package.json
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/recommended"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

main.vue

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
!@#$%^UIYTHRE
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `$(npm bin)/eslint . --ext .vue`

The `eslint` command checks only `.js` files by default. You have to specify additional extensions by `--ext` option.